# Magento check if bundle is in cart

Tags: magento

Is it possible to check if bundle product is in cart?
Bundled products are sent to cart separately so I can't get there bundle product id or sku, I could only get parts data

I need to do it in observer so check if bundle was added, or updated

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the core code (Magento 1.7.0.0) the bundle is added to the cart using the function:

`//file: app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php
//class: Mage_Checkout_CartController
public function addAction()`

just like other product types.

Are you observing

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()));
```

That `'product'` should be the bundle. But in your question you say the bundle is added separately.

For updating bundles, the event seems to be

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_item_complete',array('item' => $item, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()));
```

Can you explain in more detail what you have tried and what isn't working?